# Possible ways to compress files more than 2GB size using Microsoft CabLib / Cabinet

Tags: c++

Are there any methods to compress files more than 2GB size using *Microsoft CabLib/Cabinet* ? I see that there is a max file size limit of 2GB.

I get the error as
`Cabinet.dll does not support compressing files bigger than 2 GB.`

Comment: Why did you tag this as C++?

Comment: Why do you need to store a 2gb+ file in a cab? Maybe there's a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft published an [official specification](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/Archive_Exchange/%5bMS-CAB%5d.pdf) of the .CAB file format in 2008.

File sizes are stored as unsigned 32-bit numbers, so technically a 4GB file is possible. However, section 1.3 mentions limitations of "the file format", although likely these are limitations of the primary tools for handling them (makecab.exe and cabextract.exe):

> The CAB file format has the following limits:
>
> - A maximum uncompressed size of an input file to store in CAB: 0x7FFF8000 bytes.
> - A maximum file COUNT: 0xFFFF.
> - A maximum size of a created CAB (compressed): 0x7FFFFFFF bytes.
> - A maximum CAB-folder COUNT: 0xFFFF.
> - A maximum uncompressed data size in a CAB-folder: 0x7FFF8000 bytes.

So the answer is "no, by design".